# Find Strings(keywords) in a large MATLAB table

Tags: string, performance, matlab

I have large MATLAB tables (2.000.000 x 30), which have a timestamp in the first column and a parameter-group keyword in the second column. The third column has a parameter name and the next column the parameters value. Followed by more parameter and value pairs.

**Example data:**

```
2012-08-28 13:37:46:573, m_IVS_AU_SystemManager_FlashLast, flashLast, 9, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:46:573,m_IVS_AU_SystemManager_CPULast,cPULast,51, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:46:573,m_IVS_AU_SystemManager_NetworkLast,networkLast,0, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:48:558,m_F121_KantenKB,kantenKB,0, KantenKU, 1, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:48:589,m_F121_HmiVollstaendig,hmiVollstaendig,TRUE:0, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:49:042,m_F22_IVS_IsecTrkServiceState,isecTrkServiceState,3, ...    
2012-08-28 13:37:49:120,m_F121_HmiUpdate,hmiUpdate_PresentationsId,0, ...
```

**My Task**

I need to extract entries from this MATLAB table that match a list of keywords (for example: `m_IVS_AU_SystemManager_FlashLast`) and save the timestamp and the parameter value into a new MATLAB table.

Is there a (fast) way to do something like

```
rows = MyTable.parameterKeyword == 'm_IVS_AU_SystemManager_FlashLast'
```

like there is for numbers in MATLAB that returns a logical array containing logical true (1) if the keyword was found in that row, otherwise zero?

**Links**

- [MATLAB - tables](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?searchHighlight=table)
- [MATLAB - Access Data in a Table](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html)

Comment: Are you searching specific variables (columns) in your table or the entire thing?

Comment: I'm always searching the second column for certain keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for this, which will return a `logical` array.

For example:

```
% Dummy table
B = table(['M';'F';'F';'F'],[47;31;35;23],[68;64;62;58],...
'VariableNames',{'Gender' 'Age' 'Height'},...
'RowNames',{'Joe' 'Meg' 'Beth' 'Amy'});

mask = ismember(B.Gender, 'F');
whos mask
```

Returns:

```
mask =

     0
     1
     1
     1

  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  mask      4x1                 4  logical
```

---

As mentioned below, [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) or [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) can be used for a marginal speed increase if the query is only for one string.

I've attached simple timings below:

```
function testcode(nentries)
A = table(repmat({'hi'}, nentries, 1), 'VariableNames', {'Thing1'});

t1 = timeit(@()ismember(A.Thing1, 'hi'));
t2 = timeit(@()strcmp(A.Thing1, 'hi'));
t3 = timeit(@()strcmpi(A.Thing1, 'hi'));

tmp = ver;
fprintf(['Timing for %d entries %s:\n' ...
         '    ismember: %.5f\n' ...
         '    strcmp:   %.5f\n' ...
         '    strcmpi:  %.5f\n\n'], nentries, tmp.Release, t1, t2, t3);
end
```

For `testcode(5e6)` the timings are as follows on my machine:

```
Timing for 5000000 entries (R2016a):
    ismember: 0.09246
    strcmp:   0.06575
    strcmpi:  0.07284
```

Comment: `strcmp` can also be used if there is only one string that you are looking for, the benefit being that you can do `strcmpi` to do case insensitive matching too.

Comment: @SomeGuy true, I've added the comparison